# How to download the default service account .json key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have a google console account, but when I got to the service account section, I saw something
like this:
[image]

So there are a lot of service accounts I see for my project, and there is a Key ID along
with them also there. When I am running my Java code on my local machine, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The Application
> Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running
> in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable
> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file
> defining the credentials. See
> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
> for more information.

For this, I saw a resolution like :

> Go to Google Developers Console -> Credentials and create a default
> service account .json key. It will download a file
> like default-account-credentials.json for you when you do that.

The above step mentions that I will need to create a default service account, and then it
will automatically download the .json credentials key.  **Is it possible to download the

.json key for the service account already listed on the service accounts page

on google cloud?** I see the Key ID, but I am not sure if that is the same as the .json key
file downloaded when a new service account is created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existing .json keys **cannot** be downloaded after creation. They can only be downloaded when they are created.

Your best option would be to create a new key and for security reasons, delete the old key if not needed to avoid any potential threats regarding the old key.

To do so, go to IAM->Service Account, then select your service account and access the "Key" tab. In this tab you will see the existing key(s) and will have the option to create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly.
After you've created a service account. Click on `Edit` now go to `KEYS` tab then click on `ADD KEY` then `Create new key`. It will download JSON file for you.
Refer below snaps for reference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Existing .json keys cannot be downloaded after creation. They can only be downloaded when they are created. Your best option would be to create a new key and for security reasons, delete the old key if not needed to avoid any potential threats regarding the old key.

1. Go to IAM->Service Account, then select your service account.

[IAM->Service Account(pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVlTz.jpg)

2.Access the “Key” tab. In this tab, you will see the existing key(s) and will have the option to create a new one.
If you’ve created a service account, click on Edit, go to KEYS tab then click on ADD KEY then Create new key. It will download JSON file for you.